# how to add nodes to replica set?

Tags: mongodb, nodes, replicaset

> Reconnect to your primary node as m103-admin and add the other two
> nodes to your replica set using rs.add()

rs.add("m103:27002")

> "errmsg" : "Either all host names in a replica set configuration must
> be localhost references, or none must be; found 1 out of 2",

Comment: the error clearly says, the host name must be same for all nodes, if you have used `localhost` in first node then use the same instead of `m103`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, anytime you use "localhost" for a node, all replicas must match that instead of the replicaset name (or `replSetName`)

eg.
`rs.add("localhost:27002")`